# Gridview spacing extra area in top of parent container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am creating a shuffle game and for that, I have set 3 levels of the grid,

I have taken a fixed-sized container of 300x300 and I don't want to change its size,

here I want to place all grid buttons properly inside a grid but I am getting space at top of the grid view and due to that, the buttons are not showing properly fit.

here is my code

```
final kdecoration = BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    color: Colors.red);

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  double w = 300;
  double h = 300;
  int gridvalue = 3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(
            '$gridvalue x $gridvalue',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.blue),
          )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: h,
              width: w,
              child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: gridvalue * gridvalue,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                    crossAxisCount: gridvalue,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: kdecoration,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        (index + 1).toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                      //color: Colors.green,
                    );
                  })),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        gridvalue = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('3x3')),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        gridvalue = 4;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('4x4')),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        gridvalue = 5;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('5x5')),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

placed output image as well...[image]

Comment: what are you expecting exactly ?

Comment: blue container is 300x300 and I want to place all this buttons inside it...u can see last row not showing properly...due to that top blank area... why buttons are not starting from exactly top

Comment: Just copied your code over to dartpad and it runs correctly as you want there. is it possible you need to restart your app instead of hot reload or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can see in the Flutter inspector that by default `GridView` has padding (0, 24, 0, 0). You can remove it by adding `EdgeInsets.zero` in `GridView'.

```
GridView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ...
)
```

Comment: Great explanation.....very helpful....I got my answer as well as more info regarding Flutter inspector...Thanks a lot...upvote if my question was like that kind

Answer (score 1):

In `GridView` has a defualt padding, just you have to put `zero padding` into the `padding` like this:

```
    GridView.builder(

      padding:EdgeInsets.all(0)

)
```